# Is there a way to end a turn immediately, without moving all units?

Tags: civilization-5

In Civilization IV (and earlier) you could end a turn not having moved/actioned all of your available units. For example, if you want to leave some units in place for a turn or two, without having to explicitly tell them they have no orders - simply by clicking a button in the UI.

In V, it now insists that 'A unit has still to move' and I have to explicitly tell it to do nothing. I couldn't see a means of telling the game to end the turn immediately - is there one?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can finish your turn with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> at any time.

I didn't observe what happens if 2 units "illegally" stacked (I.e. building a unit in a garrisoned city).

Comment: I feel slightly guilty pinching the laurels back from Kaestor, but this is bang on the button. I imagine that it simply won't end the turn if you have stacked units.

Comment: Kaestur's answer was correct at the time.  The Shift-Enter capability was added in the Dec 15 patch.

Comment: This cannot be done in the OnLive version of Civilization V.

Comment: This helped me end the turn in Civ VI, where I accidently stacked a musketeer with a two-attack cannon, resulting in not being able to end the turn normally without deleting it.

Answer (score 6):

Not at the moment. You can only end the turn after you've given orders to each unit.
You can command them to skip their turn, or fortify/sentry them if you want to leave them there for a long time. If two military units or two civilian units occupy the same hex, you can't even do that - one must be moved.

Comment: It's not the end of the world... just slightly annoying. :(

Comment: As of the Dec 15 2010 patch, this Answer is no longer correct — there is a way. See the accepted Answer above.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to end the turn early using shift+enter when there are units that have not moved and there is no special situation that must be resolved before your turn ends.
Special situations include:

- New policy avaliable (annoying when Cristi Renetor is about to finish)
- New Research
- Empty production queue
- Unit can be promoted
- 2 Military units are on the same hex
- 2 Non-Military units are on the same hex

and other situations I didn't think to test but surely exist.

Comment: It is possible, using advanced game setup options, to make selecting new policies optional, which could resolve your situation with Cristo Redentor on your next game. Also makes it possible to save up policies and rush a later policy tree as soon as it unlocks, though I'm not sure whether that's actually a good idea very often.

Answer (score 3):

If you want your units to skip the turn once, just press <kbd>.</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> and then <kbd>spacebar</kbd>.

<kbd>.</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> cycle through units, and <kbd>spacebar</kbd> tells them to do nothing that turn.

Or, you could do the same but with <kbd>f</kbd> instead of <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>.

<kbd>f</kbd> makes them "sleep", meaning they aren't required to do everything each turn unless you give them orders.