# Get the button "Next turn" in Civ V instead of "Some action you can do"

Tags: civilization-5

In Civilisation V in the bottom right the button "Next turn" sometimes display the next available action instead of "Next turn" (like, choose what to build or go to the next unit without order)

I know its possible because I had a game where the button "Next turn" did show "Next turn" when some unit was not busy and some cities were building nothing but I don't find the correct settings anymore.

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to end a turn immediately, without moving all units?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/8244/88320)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are some things that must be done before you proceed, without which the game will not allow you to end the turn. These include choosing production for cities that are idle, or choosing which policies to adopt (if the option to allow deferring policies is not enabled).

However, if you simply have units that are awaiting orders, you can issue the units with commands either to 'sleep' (stay where they are until you give a new order), or 'alert' (sleep until they see an enemy), or simply to do nothing for that turn. These option are with other unit orders at the bottom left of the screen when the unit is selected.

Comment: I'm 100% sure I had idle cities, and I could pass the turn....

Comment: @tom in that case, I don't know - I've never seen an ability to pass. Why would you want to leave a city idle, when you could just set it to generate wealth or science?

Comment: Afaik you can't pass with iddle cities.

Comment: Were they idle - or were they producing science/gold?

Answer (score 7):

Right-click the "Action Required" button - if the required action isn't *actually* required (such as picking a policy when the "Deferred Policies" option is active), it will clear it from the queue and show the next required action - or the End Turn button, if that was the last one.

Note:  It's been a while since I've played Civ V, so there's a chance I'm not remembering it correctly, but I'm pretty sure.

Comment: You are indeed correct.

Answer (score 2):

In Civ V, before you start a game, check the "advanced settings" tab. There you can csee a checkbox with enables you to save policies for later (so you can actually stack up all your culture). There is also an option for saving unit promotions for the following turns.

However, Civ V does not offer the options for

- Units to do nothing (Either use the sleep option or defend option)
- Cities to produce nothing (You can produce gold or science once you got the technology)
- Technology to pause (wouldn't make sense)

Comment: The other option is to save the unit promotions for later

Comment: The units have a "Do Nothing" Option.

Comment: @JackyXie That's what I meant with sleep option

Comment: @YUNOWORK 'Sleep' and 'Do Nothing' are actually different commands. 'Do Nothing' applies only to the present turn, while 'sleep' applies until you explicitly tell it to do something different.